# Blackberry facebook sdk:Loginscreenshowing blank white screen

Tags: blackberry

I have use facebook strawberry sdk to integrate the facebook in my Blackberry application.It was working fine earlier some days of success but now it's showing blank white screen.I think it's a connection stream problem using FB with BIS, MOBILE ,WIFI network.Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: we are using modified FB BB sdk. And I've just checked - it works fine. What did you change recently that you're saying it stopped working

Comment: Hi, I have solved the FB issue myself.It was just a .4B file missing issue.

Comment: I've never heard about such files. What is it?

Comment: Hi i was using log4b.properties having defined main FB class.